# 3D Delaunay triangulation C# lib?

Tags: c#, 3d

Found some for 2D but not for 3D. Any ideas?

Comment: hey...... have you cleared about your question? then please help me.....i can't understand the given belove answer........actually i also looking for 3D Delaunay triangulation C# lib if you found any good one then please give me some suggestion.............

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).